# CSS grid-column not spanning multiple columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to use CSS grid to setup a form that has three columns: the first column is used to display the label for the input that will be listed in the second column. The third column is used to get the correct spacing of the form on the page and allow the form to scale to the page size.

I am able to separate the form labels and form inputs into columns one and two respectively, however when I cannot make a new section of the form that is centered between these two columns, it will either be in column one `labels` or column two `data`.

```css
.formContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [labels] auto [data] auto 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.formContainer>label {
  grid-column: labels;
}

.formContainer>div {
  grid-column: data;
}

.matches {
  grid-column-start: labels !important;
  grid-column-end: data !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='formContainer'>
  <label>
     <span>Name</span>
  </label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class='matches'>
    <div>No matches yet!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried making the `matches` div a different HTML element such as `article` or `span` which did not work either. Any help with trying to figure out how to make the `matches` class span between both of these columns would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We really need to know what this is supposed to look like.

Comment: If you run the code snippet, do you see how the "No matches yet!" is displayed directly under the "Name" element? I want it to look like "No matches yet!" is centered between the "Name" element and the input instead of on the left or right side.

Comment: you can use `grid-column: span 2` to the `matches` element to allow to occupy the two columns and then add `text-align: center` to center in that space - see https://jsfiddle.net/p9xenf7q/ (will add as an answer if that solves your problem)

Comment: Thanks @kukkuz, that fixed it. I tried doing the grid-column: span 2 command in the matches class itself but it did not have the same effect as the way you did it in the fiddle.

Comment: that's because `.formContainer>div` is more *specific* than `matches` - note that I've instead used `.formContainer > .matches`

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments above, you can use `grid-column: span 2` to the `matches` element to allow it to occupy two columns and then add `text-align: center` to center in that space.

---

Also note I've used `.formContainer > .matches` instead of `.matches` for *specificity* of styles (`grid-column` definition in `.formContainer > div` was overriding the `grid-column` in `.matches` as it is more specific) - see demo below:

```css
.formContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [labels] auto [data] auto 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    grid-column-gap: 10px; /* added */
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.formContainer > label {
    grid-column: labels;
}
.formContainer > div {
    grid-column: data;
}
/* changed below */
.formContainer > .matches{
    grid-column: span 2;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='formContainer'>
  <label>
     <span>Name</span>
  </label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class='matches'>
    <div>No matches yet!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```